# В чем ошибка запроса - никак найти не могу?

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT thematicspecialization.idSpecialization, thematicspecialization.SpecializationName AS SpecializationName, COUNT(ac.article_categoryIdCatgory) AS CNT

FROM thematicspecialization
LEFT JOIN( SELECT article_category.article_categoryIdCatgory
          FROM article_category
          JOIN article ON (article.idArticle = article_category.article_categoryIdArticle AND article.country = 112)) ac
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server
> version for the right syntax to use
> near 'LIMIT 0, 30' at line 7

Другой вариант этого же запроса:

```
SELECT idSpecialization, 
   thematicspecialization.SpecializationName AS SpecializationName,  
   COUNT(article_categoryId) AS CNT
FROM thematicspecialization
   LEFT JOIN article_category ON article_category.article_categoryIdCatgory =     thematicspecialization.idSpecialization
   JOIN article ON (article.idArticle = article_category.article_categoryIdArticle AND article.country = 100)
       GROUP BY idSpecialization
```

но в нем не срабатывает `article.country = 100`

Comment: Эмъ... а точно этот запрос ошибку выдает? У вас здесь нет лимита, а ошибка про него говорит

Comment: Да - я тоже обратил на это внимание. Но запрос без LIMIT

Comment: Выполните этот запрос в клиенте mysql, если он выдаст эту же ошибку, тогда приведите структуру таблиц.

Если и правда на этом запросе спотыкается, тогда, возможно, часть таблиц является вьюхами (VIEW). Приведите их тоже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет условия соединения (ON) таблицы thematicspecialization и подзапроса ac.

Comment: Точно, а я лимит искал. Видно, лимит автоматом к запросу где-то подставляется, иначе другая ошибка была бы.